# How to remove empty ul with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a list which is dynamically built from DB, but there are empty Ul items which need removing.

```
   <div class="pull-right">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled">menu</li>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Categorylst)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.CategoryName)
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="myli1" >
                    <ul id="myul">
                        @foreach (var subtoCat in Model.CategoryToSub)
                        {
                            if (item.CategoryId == subtoCat.CategoryId)
                            {

                                foreach (var sub in Model.SubCategorylst)
                                {
                                    if (sub.SubCategoryId == subtoCat.SubCategoryId)
                                    {

                            <li id="myli2">
               <a id="mya" href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(x => sub.SubCategoryName)</a>
                            </li>

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

i try to use Jquery and try some functions but still its didnt remove the empty Ul. 
what can i do to remove them  ? 
this view is partial view.

Comment: Please post generated HTML. You can check it by using view-source option in browsers

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove any `ul` elements that do not contain any `li` elements

```
$('ul').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children('li').length == 0) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Note also you are generating duplicate `ID`'s in you loops which is invalid html.

Comment: its dosnt remove the empty ones. but i tried to see if there any effect and change the code from remove to .html("test") and all the empty ones are add this text-"test". so what is worng?

Comment: Do you also have empty `li` tags within the `ul` as well?

Comment: Have you put the script at the bottom of the main page in `document.ready`? And check if there are any console errors.

Comment: I fixed up your fiddle [see update](http://jsfiddle.net/75e60e3m/3/) - you need to select jquery form the side bar. It works fine with the code above - open up developer tools and inspect the elements and you will see that the empty `ul` tags have been removed

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```js
// selects all <ul> elements, then filters the collection:
$('ul').filter(function () {
  // we keep only those elements with no child-elements
  // (note 'children' not 'childNodes'):
  return this.children.length === 0;
// we then remove those retained <ul> elements:
}).remove();
```

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul></ul>
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: its dosnt remove the empty ones.
but i tried to see if there any effect and change the code from remove to .html("test") and all the empty ones are add this text.
so what is worng?

Comment: I have no idea, the demo works for me, in iPad Air Safari/iOS7 and Chrome 37/Windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML that's produced, rather than the server-side, or templating, script? I suspect the real code, and your description are somewhat different.

Comment: This is the layout view: 
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
              @Html.Partial("_SideBar")
            </div>
            @if (IsSectionDefined("featured"))
            {
             <div class="hero-unit">
             @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
             </div>
            }
            <div class="span10">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

Comment: No, not the 'layout view,' the HTML that the user'a browser sees when it's applied that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#menu ul").each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == '')
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique you can use it like

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Categorylst)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.CategoryName)
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="myli1-@(item.Id)" >
                    <ul id="myul-@(item.Id)">
                        @foreach (var subtoCat in Model.CategoryToSub)
                        {
                            if (item.CategoryId == subtoCat.CategoryId)
                            {

                                foreach (var sub in Model.SubCategorylst)
                                {
                                    if (sub.SubCategoryId == subtoCat.SubCategoryId)
                                    {

                            <li id="myli2-@(item.Id)">
               <a id="mya" href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(x => sub.SubCategoryName)</a>
                            </li>

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
```

You can use jquery to remove `ul` element as below

```
$("ul[id^='myul']").each(function (){
if(($(this).html()==''))
{
    $(this).remove();
}
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6u0shzws/1/)

Comment: i try but it dont working. i try few functions : http://jsfiddle.net/yaniv2266/75e60e3m/2/

Comment: In left side pane there is facility to include scripts, why are u adding scripts in that block to write your own scripts